# Template suggestions not recognized

Tags: theming

I have just introduced my custom template suggestions in `MYTHEME_preprocess_node`, based on a certain field's value. Won't work somehow.

The content type is `project`. In my template folder I have already a file named `node--project.tpl.php`, and my suggestions append additional two: `node--project--pcgame.tpl.php` and `node--project--movie.tpl.php`. They are visible when I `dpm()` the variables, but are not found/applied to the node, even when I remove `node--project.tpl.php`.

Cache cleared.

Any clue as per what could be the cause?

---

The code I'm using:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node($variables){
  if(isset($variables['node'])){
    $node = $variables['node'];
    if($node->type == 'project'){
      // Determine project type based on a term field.
      $project_type = (int) $node->field_genre['und'][0]['tid'];

      switch($project_type){
        case 4:
          $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__project__pcgame';
          break;
        default:
          $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__project__movie';
      }
      dpm($variables['theme_hook_suggestions']);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: what version of drupal?

Comment: Could you show the code that creates the template suggestions?

Comment: D7. Just provided the code for you.

Comment: Is that the exact code? `$variables` needs to be passed by reference, i.e. `function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables){`

Comment: Kaboom. Shame on me :) (Still wondering why I saw the appended suggestion in `dpm`)

Comment: Because the local copy of `$variables` contains it :)

Comment: By all means! :) Thanks for nudging my sleepy brain ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You try this code.

```
 function youthemename_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
 $node = $variables['node'];
    if($node->type == 'project'){
      // Determine project type based on a term field.
      $project_type = $node->field_genre['und'][0]['tid'];

      switch($project_type){
        case 4:
          $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__project_pcgame';
          break;
        default:
          $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__project_movie';
      }
    }   
}
```

You file name should be node--project_pcgame.tpl.php and node--project_movie.tpl.php.
Clear performance cache, it should call `hook_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry).`